# How to import libraries with ESP-IDF for visual studio code?

Tags: arduino, esp32

## What I am trying to do

I have an ESP32-CAM, and I want to use Visual Studio Code, I already used the Arduino IDE at first, and it worked fine.

To work with the ESP32 on VS Code I installed the [extension from espressif](https://github.com/espressif/vscode-esp-idf-extension/blob/master/docs/tutorial/install.md), it seems to "work".

I created a new project `arduino-as-component` which give me a main.cpp like this

```cpp
#include "Arduino.h"

extern "C" void app_main()
{
    initArduino();
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
    // Do your own thing
}
```

## My problem

When I build the project that a newly created, without changing a thing, I get an error

```cpp
../main/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: Arduino.h: No such file or directory        
 #include "Arduino.h"
```

## Things I tried

I downloaded the library from the [Espressif Github](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32), and imported it inside the file `main/CMakeLists.txt`

```cpp
idf_component_register(
    SRCS "main.cpp"
    INCLUDE_DIRS "./libraries/arduino/cores/esp32"
)
```

But then I get a new error

```cpp
../main/libraries/arduino/cores/esp32/Arduino.h:28:10: fatal error: avr/pgmspace.h: No such file or directory
 #include <avr/pgmspace.h>
```

I feel like I could have endless errors like this, and that it's not the right way to import a library.

I also tried to use a code that worked on the aduino IDE, but I get similar errors.

Comment: Have you installed platformio? Then #include <arduino.h> should work just fine, if you have specified "framework = arduino" in platformio.ini